# How to find metrics about CPU/MEM for the pod running on a Kubernetes cluster on Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-pod

I have Prometheus setup via Helm from Terraform and it's is configured to connect to my Kubernetes cluster. I open my Prometheus but I am not sure which metric to choose from the list to be able to view the CPU/MEM of running pods/jobs.
Here are all the pods running with the command (**test1** is the kube **namespace**):

```
kubectl -n test1 get pods
```

[podsrunning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdNNe.png)

When, I am on Prometheus, I see many metrics related to CPU, but not sure which one to choose:

[prom1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wyQd.png)

I tried to choose one, but the namespace = prometheus and it uses `prometheus-node-exporter` and I don't see my cluster or my namespace `test1` anywhere here.

[prom2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Mz2.png)

Could you please help me? Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE SCREENSHOT**
***UPDATE SCREENSHOT***
I need to concentrate on this specific namespace, normally with the command:
`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep hermatwin`
I see the first line with namespace = `jobs` I think this is namespace.
[image: promQL1]

No result when set calendar to last Friday:
[image: promQL2]

**UPDATE SCREENSHOT April 20**
I tried to select 2 days with starting date on last Saturday 17 April but I don't see any result:
[image: noResult1]

ANd, if I remove (namespace="jobs") condition, I don't see any result either:
[image: noresult2]

I tried to rerun the job (simulation jobs) again just now and tried to execute the prometheus query while the job was still running mode but I don't get any result :-( Here you can see my jobs where running.

[image: jobsRunning]

I don't get any result:
[image: noresult3]

When using simple filter, just `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`, I can see the namespace="jobs"
[image: resultnamespacejobs]

[image: iRate1]

[image: ResultJob]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node_cpu_seconds_total` is a metric from `node-exporter`, the exporter that brings machine statistics and its metrics are prefixed with `node_`. You need metrics from `cAdvisor`, this one produces metrics related to containers and they are prefixed with `container_`:

```
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total
container_cpu_load_average_10s
container_memory_usage_bytes
container_memory_rss
```

Here are some basic queries for you to get started. Be ready that they may require tweaking (you may have different label names):

#### CPU Utilisation Per Pod

```
sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="POD", container=~".+"}[2m])) by (pod)
```

#### RAM Usage Per Pod

```
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{container!="POD", container=~".+"}) by (pod)
```

#### In/Out Traffic Rate Per Pod

Beware that pods with `host` network mode (not isolated) show traffic rate for the whole node. `* 8` is to convert bytes to bits for convenience (MBit/s, GBit/s, etc).

```
# incoming
sum(irate(container_network_receive_bytes_total[2m])) by (pod) * 8
# outgoing
sum(irate(container_network_transmit_bytes_total[2m])) by (pod) * 8
```

Comment: thank you so much!! I will try this on my side.

Comment: Hello @anemyte I would like to understand better your first query, what does `{container!="POD", container=~".+"}` this mean ?

Comment: Also @anemyte please check my updated screenshot, I need to concentrate on this specific namespace, normally with the command: `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep hermatwin`
However, when I modify your query to `sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="jobs", namespace=~".+"}[2m])) by (pod)`
I don't see anything, but when I modify to `kube-system` like this:
`sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="kube-system", namespace=~".+"}[2m])) by (pod)`, I see correct info. How can I see the info about `hermatwin-56041586-test1` from my screenshot ?

Comment: `container!="POD"` means 'match metrics where `container` label is not  `POD`', `container=~".+"` means 'match metrics where `container` label contains something (not empty)'. These exclude some special labels that present in my setup (see the [link](https://i.imgur.com/MBUvX99.png)). You may remove these conditions if you wish to see those values.

Comment: @shuti as for the second question, I can only suggest that the metrics for the job are not present now, because the job ran some days ago. It should be there if you set the range for the query (https://i.imgur.com/B4fTzRr.png).

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer @anemyte however I tried to set the calendar to last Friday (this is when I executed this job) but I still get nothing (pls see my screenshot above). This is the query I modified:
`sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="jobs", namespace=~".+"}[2m])) by (pod)`
Is there something wrong in my query ?

Comment: @shuti the query is fine, as far as I can see; although the second condition seems unnecessary but it shouldn't do any harm. Show me another screnshoot, this time using graph over 2 days with the beginning on Saturday https://i.imgur.com/LvloHA4.png

Comment: @shuti it looks like there is no metrics for `jobs` namespace. If you remove the condition for it (`namespace="jobs"`), can you see the required job on the graph?

Comment: thank you so much again for your help as I have struggling with this topic for many weeks no without any help. Pls, see my new screenshots in the post above `Update Screenshot April 20` unfortunately I don't have any result which is strange because as far as I heard, Prometheus keep 15 days of historic data right? I don't know why I cannot see metrics for `jobs` namespace, I am going to launch this job now and see if I see metric or not.

Comment: @shuti I see from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wyQd.png) screenshot that the metrics are there; try using a simple query without any functions (e.g. just `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total`) and use a large graph interval (several days from now). You should see when metrics begin and end and which labels are present.

Comment: I started the jobs again, please see my screenshots above in my post, I queried in Prometheus while the jobs were running but I didn't get any results. Here is the query I used. How come the metrics for namespace `jobs` are not available? I can see CPU/MEM of these processes on google cloud but I want to use Prometheus for the historic data because on google cloud, we cannot see this info for completed jobs.
`sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="jobs", namespace=~".+"}[2m])) by (pod)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply @anemyte I do see now `jobs` namespace of the pod I want to check, however I wonder why don't I get any result for the simple metric `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` when I set the end time on last saturday and 2D? I want to try to check the pod that was done last Friday. I thought that it would at least give me some result, but I don't see anything.

Comment: @shuti how long does the job take? And what is your scrape interval for `kubelet` job? To see the latter click Status -> configuration, find `job_name: kubelet`, check `scrape_interval` value. If there is no such key, it's defined under `global`.

Comment: this job usually take about 46 seconds to 1 minute until it is completed. This is config I found about kubelet, is it the correct one ?

`- job_name: prometheus/prometheus-kube-prometheus-kubelet/0`
  honor_labels: true
  honor_timestamps: true
  `scrape_interval: 30s`
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
.............
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_k8s_app]
    `regex: kubelet`

I have another section of kubelet with `kubelet/1` for `job_name`

Comment: @shuti that's a problem. Depending on how long the job run there could be one to three data points (it gathers metrics once in 30s); and you need _at least_ two to calculate `rate` or `irate` of CPU utilisation. And even if there's two, you will see a very short line when the job ran. Try both queries with several days long graph range: 1) `sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="jobs"}[1m])) by (pod)` 2) `sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{namespace="jobs"}[1m])) by (pod)`. If there's anything with two data points you should see a very short line on the graph.

Comment: thank you, I tried both queries and specified `1w` without any `End time` is that what you wanted me to try? However with both rate and irate, I don't get any result.
[Prometheus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRCmf.png)

Comment: @shuti then it seems there's just not enough data to calculate rates. Let's prove this, launch a normal pod (not a job) in `jobs` namespace for 2 minutes. The same queries should show it.

Comment: I did a little test and ran a pod in namespace `jobs` and it's still running for the pasted 7 minutes and I can see very well the data, esp when I change the time range to 30 minutes.
[Result Jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0whc.png)
My question is what does `End time` means, does it means, to get metrics for pod that ends on the specific date? Also, to conclude this issue is that when pod that finished too fast (less than 1 mins) we cannot see the past metrics for these pods because not enough data points?

Comment: @shuti `End time` is when the graph ends, the default is 'now'. The time range is counted from it, so with the time range of 30m you see a graph like 30m ago to now. If `end time` is 09:00 and time range 30m, you see a graph for 08:30-09:00.

Comment: @shuti as for the quick-time jobs, yes the problem is in low amount of data. You can fix this by making prometheus to scrape kubelet job more often than 30s. This way you'll have more datapoints, but obviously you'll need more physical space for storage. If you decided to go with it, I think you should find the option somewhere in the `values.yml` for the chart.

Comment: Thank you so much @anemyte for your help. You are my hero! ^_^ You have helped me a lot with Prometheus. I will try playing around with this config.