# Is there a way to log Kubernetes Pod memory usage, in a container running an application built on Node.js

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, logging, memory, out-of-memory

I have a Kubernetes pod which shuts down and restarts itself because it went out of memory. There are multiple child processes which run asynchronously and use memory. I want each of them to log how much memory is available/used on the Kubernetes pod. The logs should be with the other Node js logs.

I know of `process.memoryUsage()`, `os.totalmem()`, `os.freemem()`

Which provide the following output respectively

```
{"ts":"2021-04-21T10:52:50.299Z","msg":"Node Memory Stats:{\"rss\":125792256,\"heapTotal\":94720000,\"heapUsed\":48927816,\"external\":1668086}","logger":"___","level":"info"}
{"ts":"2021-04-21T10:52:50.300Z","msg":"OS/POD Total Memory:17179869184, OS/POD Free memory:87195648","logger":"___","level":"info"}
```

I was wondering if there is any way I could do a system call to the pod, get its resources, and log in Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check the values from `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/` and `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/`:

For the current **CPU** usage do a

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.usage
```

For the current **memory** usage do a

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes
```

Hint: Make sure you have added the resources section (requests and limits) to the deployment so that it can calculate the usage based on cgroup.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62717009/1560953

Comment: Eventually, this answer worked. I was able to print out this file directly from NodeJS by using file system. There was no need of any external library.