# How to check number of cores and ram capacity left in kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-metrics

I have a Kubernetes cluster of around 18 nodes where few are with 4 cores and 16G RAM, and few are with 16 core and 64G RAM, and there are around 25-30 applications running on
the cluster.

Each of the applications are configured with requests and limit parameter, around 2-3cores & 4-8G ram and allocated to each of the application.

Now how do I get the current utilization report saying how many cores/ram I am left within the current cluster? before deploying any new application.

I tried using the below commands:

```
kubectl top no;    kubectl describe no [node-name]
```

These are not giving me the exact no. of cores or ram I am left with.

Any leads to this will help a lot.

Note: I am using version 1.19 of Kubernetes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking kubernetes pod CPU and memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531646/checking-kubernetes-pod-cpu-and-memory)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `kubectl` plugin to view the resourses capacity, usage etc.

Here, are few related plugins.

- [etopeter/kubectl-view-utilization](https://github.com/etopeter/kubectl-view-utilization)
- [davidB/kubectl-view-allocations](https://github.com/davidB/kubectl-view-allocations)
- [robscott/kube-capacity](https://github.com/robscott/kube-capacity)

You can use [krew](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user-guide/quickstart/) to install those plugins.

Comment: Is there any native kubectl command to check this?

Comment: There is `kubectl top` command but it require you to install Metrics Server in your cluster.

Comment: Sure I will try this

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl describe node <insert-node-name-here>`

You should see something like this:

```yaml
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                       Requests      Limits
  --------                       --------      ------
  cpu                            1130m (59%)   3750m (197%)
  memory                         4836Mi (90%)  7988Mi (148%)
  ephemeral-storage              0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi                  0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi                  0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-azure-disk  0             0
```