# Is there a way to measure CPU usage inside the Kubernetes POD?

Tags: monitoring, cpu-usage, kubernetes-pod, traffic, top-command

In CNF world, measuring the CPU usage on a POD with usual commands for example, top command doesnot actually provide the POD's actual CPU usage, instead it will be like you run it on the host system/node because the pod is using kernel of the host system.

We have to periodically monitor the CPU usage inside the POD and throttle the traffic. Is there a way to measure the CPU usage inside the POD?

top command doesnot actually provide the POD's actual CPU usage, instead it provides the host system/node usage, because the pod is using kernel of the host system.

Answer (score 0):

From the way you present the question I think you don't want the answer "install a monitoring stack consisting of Prometheus, Alertmanager and Grafana to monitor the infrastructure".

You could simply do these steps:

1.Log into the Pod

```
kubectl -n NAMESPACE exec -it POD_NAME —- bash (or sh)
```

2.Run the command

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.usage
```

for cpu usage

Take a look at this docs:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-cpuacct

[Checking kubernetes pod CPU and memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531646/checking-kubernetes-pod-cpu-and-memory)